# problem enabling repos in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

When I do a repolist on a RHEL 7 machine I see a number of repos that are disabled:

```
rh-gluster-3-client-for-rhel-7-server-rpms/x86_64                                                   Red Hat Storage Native Client for RHEL 7 (RPMs)                                                                            disabled
rhel-7-fast-datapath-rpms/x86_64                                                                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Fast Datapath (RHEL 7 Server) (RPMs)                                                              disabled
rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-rpms/x86_64                                                               Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.4 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server                                                      disabled
!rhel-7-server-ansible-2.6-rpms/x86_64                                                              Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.6 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server                                                      disabled
```

And I notice some of them have an exclamation at the start of them.

If I do:

```
yum --enable=rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-rpms/x86_64
```

I get

```
Error getting repository data for rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-rpms/x86_64, repository not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is there an exclamation for some of them?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the output of `yum repolist` included the architecture component (`/x86_64`), which isn't part of the repo name/ID. To enable a repo (permanently), you'd want to use [yum-config-manager](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories#sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories) (RHEL7 link):

> ```
> yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-rpms
> ```

To enable that repo for a single yum command, you'd use:

```
yum --enablerepo=rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-rpms [command ...]
```

---

As for:

> Why is there an exclamation for some of them?

This is described in `man yum` -- in the `repolist` section:

> ... In non-verbose mode the first column will start with a ... ´!´ if the repository has metadata that is expired. ...

You can resolve that by running `yum makecache` -- which it should be noted, only updates the metadata for **enabled** repos.